# most times OCR is recognizing < as K. Is there a way around this?

Tags: java, android, google-api, ocr

I wrote a code to read MRZ on passports using Google Text Api from this link [Text Api Code Lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0).

Everything is working fine, but most times it reads < from the MRZ on the passport as K, and it does not read all 88 characters on the MRZ.

For example OCR is suppose to read

`P<UTOERIKSSON<<ANNA<MARIA<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
L898902C<3UTO6908061F9406236ZE184226B<<<<<14`,

but it outputs something like this

`PKUTOERIKSSON ANNA<MARIAK<<KK<<<<
L898902C<3UTO6908061F9406236ZE184226Bk<<<14`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Get a better OCR library?  That's part of why computer vision isn't a solved science, and why for things that need to be recognized reliably we use barcodes and similar technology rather than text.

Comment: Can you recommend a better OCR library for me?

Answer (score 1):

I am using migrated version of same library on my sample project and I have never had an issue. 
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/

It reads mrz text too fast and correctly. Before I have tried Google Tesseract based OCR library and the result was not good on my entry level cell phone. Then I have replaced OCR library to Google MLKit Text recognition, it reads passport / id card texts clearly and so fast. I have parse read text with MRZInfo and validate fields are correct.

Here is a sample of my implementation:

https://github.com/alimertozdemir/EPassportNFCReader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alimert/mlkit/text/TextRecognitionProcessor.java

```
    private void filterScannedText(GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay, Text.Element element) {
    GraphicOverlay.Graphic textGraphic = new TextGraphic(graphicOverlay, element, Color.GREEN);
    scannedTextBuffer += element.getText();
    String docPrefix;
    if(scannedTextBuffer.contains(StringUtil.TYPE_PASSPORT) || scannedTextBuffer.contains(StringUtil.TYPE_ID_CARD)) {
        graphicOverlay.add(textGraphic);
        docPrefix = scannedTextBuffer.contains(StringUtil.TYPE_PASSPORT) ? StringUtil.TYPE_PASSPORT : StringUtil.TYPE_ID_CARD;
        scannedTextBuffer = scannedTextBuffer.substring(scannedTextBuffer.indexOf(docPrefix));
        finishScanning(scannedTextBuffer);
    }
}
```